# Convergent's numerators of the continued fraction for $\pi$

Tags: analysis, sequences-and-series, continued-fractions

Call $C_{\pi} = \{ 1,3,22,333,355,… \}$, it´s the sequence of the numerators of convergents of the continued fraction for $\pi$, its OEIS' A002485, http://oeis.org/A002485.

Let $n \in C_{\pi}$, such that $n \geq 208341$.

If $k$ is the digit's number of $n$, then $|sin(n)| < 10^{-(k-1)}$.

I tried to show it, but the only thing that I can do is check the affirmation.

Comment: Make use of the fact that the convergents are very good approximations to $\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p_k/q_k$ is the $k$'th convergent of the simple continued fraction for an irrational number $x$, we have $|\sin(p_k - q_k x)| < |p_k - q_k x| < 1/q_k$.

Comment: I understand that the inequality became bounded $sin(p_{k} - q_{k}x)$ like we wanted, but I can't percept why it's imply $sin(p_{k})$ is bounded too.

Comment: $\sin(p - q \pi) = \pm \sin(p)$ when $q$ is an integer.